# Finding General Formula of a Determinant

Tags: determinant

Let $A=(a_{ij})\in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be defined by

$$
a_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
i, & \text{if } i+j=n+1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Compute $\det (A)$

---

> After calculation I get that it may be $(-1)^{n-1}n!$. Am I right?

Comment: please test it on some concrete matrix,for example third order,fourth order

Comment: And then prove it by induction :)

Comment: i like this word induction :D

Comment: @ghugni is there any question or problem was solved?

Answer (score 1):

for example let us  take  $3X3$ matrix,then it would be  following matrix

a=[0 0 1;0 2 0;3 0 0]

a =

```
 0     0     1
 0     2     0
 3     0     0


det(a)

ans =

    -6
```

in your case  if we compute $(-1)^{n-1}*n!=(-1)^2*n!=6$

maybe it is   $(-1)^{n}*n!$

Answer (score 1):

These are matrices with only off-diagonal elements, with values being the row numbers. So the number of negative factors is the same for if it was a diagonal matrix: **even** for an **even** $n$, and **odd** for an **odd** $n$. 
So looks like the answer is:

$$|A|=(-1)^nn!$$

Comment: i was thinking also like this,+1

Answer (score 0):

Just take $n=2$ then accordingly given conditions

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 2 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}$$
$Det(A)= -2=-2!$

& For $n=3$ $Det(A)= -6=-3!$

For $n=4$ $Det(A)=24=4!$

This suggests us the general formula for det. of such type of matrix is $$(-1)^{(n-1)(\frac{n}{2})}.n!$$

I think u can see it very easily Thanks.